# Vue/Nuxt.js Image Slide

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, slide

While developing a site, I have faced some problems in Vue Bootstrap Slide.
I have to make Vue bootstrap slide that show 3 items at a once(there are many images in this slide) and the center image among those 3 images should be larger than the other.

Comment: I think this might help. With only few changes you can change 6 images to 3.
https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/?ref=madewithvuejs.com

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? Can you share some code please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.